# Using nth of type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating a website part of which consists of a long page containing full page slides. On each of these slides there will be 2 images which can be clicked to open a modal to view them.

The problem I'm having with my modal is that I place it at a certain distance from the top and this applies to every instance of the modal- fine for the first slide but less so for each subsequent slide.

One way I have considered to try and tackle this is nth child.
I know that there will be 2 images on each slide so I can add 100% to 3 and 4, 200% to 5 and 6, etc....

But....I don't seem to be able to get nth child working.
My css basically says:

```css
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:blue;
    left: 22%;
 width:80%;
 height:90%;
 top:103%;
    z-index: 9;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
 }

.modalDialog:nth-of-type(1){
    color:yellow;
    top: 203%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
  <div class="title"> 
        blah blah
  </div>
    <div class="tooltip">     
        <a href="#openModal">
            <img src="ONE.png">  
            <p class="tooltiptext">yup</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <a href="#openModal2">
            <img src="two.png">  
             <p class="tooltiptext">aye..</p>
        </a>
    </div> 
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>descriptions</h2>
                <img src="ONE.png">
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
            <div>   
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <h2>desc</h2>
                    <img src="two.png">
            </div>
        </div>      
  </div>
```

With the slide number counting up and the  openModal also continuously counting up (so slide3 has openModal5 and 6)

Now the problem is. I just can't seem to get nth of type or something I've tried, nth of child, to do anything.
Never mind doing what I want and putting the modals for the subsequent pages in different places, I can't even get the second modal on the first page to change- as you see from the version above I'm trying to just get some response.

What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: What about the `<p><img src="ONE.png"</p>`? There’s something missing.

Comment: According to the docs, `nth-of-type` (and `nth-child`) should have a value containing an `n`. Your problem goes away if you do `nth-of-type(1n)`.

Comment: `nth-of-type` works just for tags ... and also travels on on the same parent, you can't travel accross all document searching like you want.

Comment: Won't this just make all of them 203% from the top each time?

Comment: Real problem here are other styles ... for the modal wich is the position? absolute? relative to?  wich is the expected output?

Comment: @Xufox- nothing there, don't know how that got mixed in there when I was copying it over.

Comment: @somethinghere- With or without n it isn't working. I'm trying with using odd and even too.

Comment: @BSMP- yes. I'm just trying to get SOMETHING to happen right now. Once I get this nth of type or nth child working I'll work on making them do what I actually want.

Comment: added rest of my modal code

Comment: If you are using fixed position I don't see why you need those values for top ... all can be always at top 10% for example .... 103% will set it out of the view

Comment: Its a one page website. 3% is top of the first 'page', 103% is top of the second 'page'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[id$="Modal1"]`

> **[attr$=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose last value is suffixed by "value".

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: blue;
  left: 22%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 103%;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/*Starts with string */
[id^="openModal"] {
  position: relative;
  top: 200%;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity:1
}
/*Ends with string */
[id$="Modal1"] {
 background : red
}
[id$="Modal2"] {
 background : yellow
}
```

```html
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <a href="#openModal">
      <img src="ONE.png">
      <p class="tooltiptext">yup</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <a href="#openModal2">
      <img src="two.png">
      <p class="tooltiptext">aye..</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>descriptions</h2>
      <img src="ONE.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>desc</h2>
      <img src="two.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: excellent!
All that seems to be necessary is

[id$="Modal1"] {
  top: 103%;
 color:green;
 z-index: 5;
}  but otherwise it has solved my issue. Its looking for ids that contain the string modalx and modifying it right? Cheers!

Comment: I wonder, for the purpose of saving (vritual) paper is there a way to do id= modal1 or modal2?

Comment: are the properties the same?

Comment: yes, there will be 2 on each page so each set will be exactly the same. 1 and 2 the same, 3 and 4 the same, etc...

Comment: then you can use comma `,` like this: `[id$="Modal1"], [id$="Modal2"] {background : red}`  `[id$="Modal3"], [id$="Modal4"] {background : yellow}`

Answer (score 0):

`nth-of-type(n)`  counts the *tag* type (on the same level), not the class: In your case it will select the nth `div` tag, not the nth tag with class `.modalDialog`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest doing this a different way, instead of creating a new style to select each nth-of-type like you do in the following code:

```
.modalDialog:nth-of-type(1){
    color:yellow;
    top: 203%;
}
```

The modal dialogue should set a margin for how far it should be from the top, like this:

```
.modalDialog{
    color:yellow;
    margin: 15% auto;
}
```